# NSolve won't act on very large powers

Tags: equation-solving, numerics

I noticed that `NSolve` isn't running properly when I have some seemingly harmless numbers in my expression. Here is a simple example:

```
NSolve[1/x == 10^15, x]
(* {} *)
```

Interestingly, if I run this over a list of different powers many of them are failing (but not all):

```
Cases[#, {x_, {}}] &@ Table[{i, NSolve[1/x == 10^i, x]}, {i, Range[1, 50]}]
(* {{15, {}}, {18, {}}, {21, {}}, {23, {}}, {24, {}}, {25, {}},
 {26, {}}, {29, {}}, {30, {}}, {32, {}}, {34, {}}, {39, {}},
 {42, {}}, {43, {}}, {45, {}}, {49, {}}} *)
```

Why is this happening and is there is a generic workaround?

Note: I'm using *Mathematica* on Linux x86 10.0.2.0

Comment: Huh. If you set `WorkingPrecision` to anything other than the default value, it works.

Comment: I can confirm this behavior on MM 10.2.0.0 on Mac OS.  What's more, I get a different set of non-working value if I use `(10.0)^i` instead:  `{{15, {}}, {18, {}}, {21, {}}, {24, {}}, {30, {}}, {34, {}}, {37, {}}, {43, {}}, {46, {}}}`  I wonder if the answer is related to the binary (floating-point) representation of 1/10 or something like that.

Comment: Its not about the exact integer, this gives null results too: `Cases[Table[{v, NSolve[1/x == v, x]}, {v,  RandomReal[10, 1000] 10^13}], {x_, {}}]`

Comment: Simpler is to use `Solve`, which works fine.

Answer (score 3):

If all your problems are of this sort, simply use `Solve`.  `Solve` acts by manipulating the *symbols*, which in these cases is trivial, so that

```
Solve[1/x == 10^(-50), x]
```

gives the proper answer directly.  *Mathematica* recognizes this equation as $1/x = a$ and solves, yielding $a = 1/x = 10^{(-(-50))} = 10^{50}$.

In contrast, `NSolve` performs a *numerical* solution, and thus at some stage likley exceeding `MachinePrecision`, leading to numerical errors.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately, I am unable to use Solve for my actual problem (which is more intricate then the above equation).

Comment: @Jeff, did you try increasing the setting of `WorkingPrecision` instead?

Comment: I did. While it sometimes fixed the toy problem above (I found it depended on the choice of WorkingPrecision), it didn't fix my actual issue. Not sure if its because there are multiple problems at hand.

Comment: Well, @JeffDror, an important lesson:  Always ask the simplest version of a problem whose answer will actually help you.  It is much better to ask your *true* question, and I urge you to do so if you want help from us.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork: The reason I like posting questions here is more to better understand Mathematica than to actually solve the problem I have at hand (I can usually find some workaround). In this instance, the answer seems simply to be a immovable bug in Mathematica which is good enough for me.

Comment: @JeffDror:  When you write that our efforts "...didn't fix my actual issue" it might engender a mild resentment among those here motivated to help.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork: Okay, I'll keep it in mind. I just meant that I suspect it wasn't a general solution.

Answer (score 2):

Is there any reason you can't solve for logarithms? If you do, `NSolve` handles the provided example pretty straightforwardly:

```
Thread[y -> (Exp[y] /. NSolve[-y == Log[10^(-50)], y])]    
(* {y -> 1.*10^50} *)
```